# Running C file in Visual Studio Code (Windows) without error - #include stdio.h cannot open source file

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include-path, set-include-path

1. How to run a C file in Visual Studio without:

   - having error message `#include stdio.h cannot open source file`; and
   - **not** download mingw for Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Download](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) Visual Studio Code & make sure you install `C/C++` & `C/C++ Extension Pack` in extensions
2. Go to `Remote Explorer` -> Select `Connect to WSL`
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLVNw.png)
3. Go to File -> Open Folder -> enter C directory `/mnt/c`
4. Enter `Ctrl + Shift + P` -> Type `configurations` -> Select `(UI)` -> Enter `/usr/bin/gcc` in `Complier Path`
5. Lastly, **BE VERY SURE** to set `IntelliSenseMode` to `linux-gcc-x64` or any `x64` compiler instead of `x86`  because `x64` is for 32-bit compilers while `x84` is for 64-bit compilers which gcc in `Ubuntu` workspace might not support.
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT8zU.png)
6. Voila! There should not be any `squiggle lines` afterwards.

Please `Vote` this answer if it helped you!